# find multiple items from mongoDB in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to find multiple things like item's ID and item's Item's Status.
but every time i get false. 
Node.js code:

```
app.post('/product', function (req, res) {

var collection = req.db.get('itemslist');
var id = req.body.id;
var status = req.body.status;
collection.findOne({id: id, status: status}, function(e, doc){
console.log(id, status);
if (doc == true){
    res.send('true');
    }
else {
    res.send('false');
}

});
});
```

where i am going wrong?

Comment: `doc` is a document and not a boolean. try `if (!doc){    res.send('false');    }
else {    res.send('true');}

Comment: It Worked. Thanks for the help. Answer my question i will accept it.

Comment: and please also explain this `doc` thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doc` is a document and not a boolean. try `if (!doc){ res.send('false'); } else { res.send('true');}`

When you use `collection.findone()` it returns: "one document that satisfies the criteria specified as the first argument to this method."

i.e. the first document from your collection, a document is an object which contains all the data.

You can find more info [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)

Comment: Its working but now i am using `collection.findOneAndUpdate()` to update data as well but am getting true everytime even data base is updated.
`app.post('/ground', function (req, res) {

    var collection = req.db.get('groundlist');
    var id = req.body.id;
    var status = req.body.status;
    collection.findOneAndUpdate({status: status, id: id},{$set:{status:"booked"}}, function(e, doc){
console.log(id, status);
    if (!doc){
        res.send(false);
        console.log(e);
        }
    else {
        res.send(true);
    }

    });
});`
this is my update code.

Comment: When `upsert` flag is true (false by default)- When there is no matching document the `findOneAndUpdate()` will create one. I don't see you use this option so you should get false when there is no matching document with id and status. by the way, to handle errors, you can use: `... function (e, doc) {console.log(id, status);if (e) {console.log(e);} else if (!doc) {res.send(false);} else {res.send(true);}});`